# js_exception TypeError search.load is not a function

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Im trying to make a code that's run a saved search and log an alert in the scree with some information, and also get that information and make some others process.

Im just following the Netsuite SuiteScript course, and im new in Netsuite development.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript 
 * @NModuleScope Public 
 */
define(['N/search'], function () {
    function rodabusca(search) {
        var buscaLicencas = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch_pesquisa_relacao_licencas'
        });
        var resultado = buscaLicencas.run().getRange({
            start: 0,
            end: 999
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
            var cliente = result[i].getValue({ name: 'values' });
            alert('Dado captado com sucesso!');
        }
    };
    return { pageInit: rodabusca };
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the 'N/search' module into the callback function for it to be available.  In other words, your first line should be:

```
define(['N/search'], function (search) {
```

rather than

```
define(['N/search'], function () {
```